# Expression statement in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

If in Java `i++` is an expression and `i++;` is an expression statement and semicolons(;) are optional in Kotlin, is `i++` an expression or expression statement in Kotlin?

Comment: Can you assign the value of `i++` to a variable? Can you pass `i++` as an argument of a method? If you can, then it means that `i++` has a value, and is thus an expression.

Comment: So is there any instance where i++ can be an expression statement?

Comment: `i++` is an expression. If you don't do anything with its value, you use it as a statement, i.e. only for the side-effects its has, and not for its value.

Comment: Alright. Can you provide your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i++` is an expression, because it has a value, that you can assign to a variable, pass as an argument to a method, etc.

If you just have `i++`, and don't do anything with its value, you use it as a statement, i.e. only for the side-effects it has, and not for its value.